# Make an Android Project to maven Project using Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and I have no experience at all with Maven.
I have an android project created with Android Studio and I have to make this project a Maven project in order to provide the repository to another partner so they can integrate different partner's work into a one project.

The problem is that I cannot find how to make this maven repository and import my project.
Any one who can help please?